# Why is configure not called on my Guice module?

Tags: java, guice

I have a guice module added to the injector using 
injector = Guice.createInjector(...

but its configure method is never called.

Is there something I m missing?.

```
injector = Guice.createInjector(....,new XModule(),....

import net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient;
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;

public class XModule extends AbstractModule {

@Override
protected void configure() {
//Never called
}
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it's not being called? There might be some other issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configure is only called when the injection is actually hit. i.e. when you try an inject an object of that type. Dumb question sorry.

Comment: Your answer is useful. Your criticism of the question is not.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say. Guice should call `configure` on all modules it's given so I can only assume something else is going on that you aren't showing. Can you post a short, self-contained example that demonstrates this behavior?